# real time applications of AVL trees

Tags: avl-tree

I am aware of some of the advantages of using AVL trees such as getting better time complexity to search an element `log(number of nodes in tree)` since the tree has self-balancing capabilities.
I am curious - what are some of the real time applications of AVL trees? Like in real world, for what applications/use-cases have the AVL trees been used?